# Check url in SitemapSpider before parse

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a spider that daily crawl sites with hundreds of thousands of pages. The pages themselves rarely changes when they have been published, but they are removed/added all the time. Most pages are only active for a couple of weeks or months.

So I want to stop my Spider from crawling the pages after they have already been crawled once, and instead just make a quick SQL Update call to my database if the page is found in the Sitemap (Which means, the page still exists and I can update a "last_found_date" column).

I guess the best way to do this is to override the `SitemapSpider` and prevent the spider from sending the requests in the first place if the url already exists in my database.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by overriding the `start_request()` function and creating my own `parse_sitemap()` function based on the `SitemapSpider` `_parse_sitemap()` function.

I did it in the following way:

1) In your `__init__()`, of your own Spider. Call the parents init. This is required for some of the functionality in the parse_sitemap function.

```
def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
    super(HemnetSitemapSpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
```

2) You need to create your own `start_request()`. If not the default `start_request()` will call the parents `_parse_sitemap()`.

```
def start_requests(self):
    return (scrapy.Request(x, callback=self.parse_sitemap) for x in self.sitemap_urls)
```

3) Lastly you need to create your own `parse_sitemap()`. Go into your scrapy package folder and open the original `sitemap.py` file, containing the parent class, and copy the whole function for `_parse_sitemap()`.

In that function there is a part that says:

```
elif s.type == 'urlset':
    ...
```

This is the part that finds  a URL that is not a child sitemap, and this is where you want to do your check to see if the URL is already in your database or w/e you want to do.

So my `parse_sitemap()` function looks something like this:

```
def parse_sitemap(self, response):
    if response.url.endswith('/robots.txt'):
        for url in sitemap_urls_from_robots(response.body):
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_sitemap)
    else:
        body = self._get_sitemap_body(response)
        if body is None:
            log.msg(format="Ignoring invalid sitemap: %(response)s",
                    level=log.WARNING, spider=self, response=response)
            return

        s = Sitemap(body)
        if s.type == 'sitemapindex':
            for loc in iterloc(s, self.sitemap_alternate_links):
                if any(x.search(loc) for x in self._follow):
                    yield Request(loc, callback=self.parse_sitemap)
        # If this is a URL Set, then check if it has been parsed before.
        elif s.type == 'urlset':
            for loc in iterloc(s):
                for r, c in self._cbs:
                    if r.search(loc):
                        # Check here for history URL
                        try:
                            self.cursor.execute('_YOUR_SQL_QUERY_', [loc])
                            row = self.cursor.fetchone()
                        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
                            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

                        # If no row exist from that source, then send the request.
                        if row is None:
                            yield Request(loc, callback=c)
                        # Else, if this source already exists. Update the date_updated field
                        else:
                            # Update date_updated
                            try:
                                date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                                self.cursor.execute('_YOUR_UPDATE_QUERY_', [date, row[0]])
                            except MySQLdb.Error, e:
                                print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

                        # Break for loop.
                        break
```